# Pandas div with multiple index

Tags: python, pandas, divide

I have been facing the following problem. I have a dataframe with multiple index (three here):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, 8, size = (8, 1)))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1990, 'Women','type_A'), (1990, 'Women','type_B'),(1990, 'Men','type_A'), (1990, 'Men','type_B'), 
(1991, 'Women','type_A'), (1991, 'Women','type_B'),(1991, 'Men','type_A'), (1991, 'Men','type_B')])
df.index.names = ['Year', 'Gender','Type']
df.columns = ['Total']
```

which looks like:

```
                     Total
Year Gender Type         
1990 Women  type_A      5
            type_B      7
     Men    type_A      6
            type_B      2
1991 Women  type_A      2
            type_B      6
     Men    type_A      3
            type_B      5
```

I have been trying to compute the share of each `Type` and `Gender` by `Year` but I have not found any clear answer on SOF. At the end of the day I need to get the following df:

```
                     Share
Year Gender Type          
1990 Women  type_A  0.4166
            type_B  0.5833
     Men    type_A  0.7500
            type_B  0.2500
1991 Women  type_A  0.2500
            type_B  0.7500
     Men    type_A  0.3750
            type_B  0.6250
```

Normally, I would do it using `div` function but it does not seem to work here with more than one index. Has someone faced a similar situation ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to calculate the sum group by year and gender and then divide the original data frame by the sum (the result is slightly different because you didn't set seed for the random generator):

```
df/df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).transform('sum')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I love you. Just what does the level [0,1] mean ? Is-there where you define the index to compute the share like index 0 is Year and index 1 is gender ? Plus, do you know why 'df/df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()' does not work ?

Comment: `level` [0,1] means the level of multi-index, so your multi-index has three levels in total, 0 and 1 represents the first two levels `year` and `Gender` respectively. `df/df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()` doesn't work because `groupby().sum()` syntax reduces the data frame to a smaller dimension and thus the dimension doesn't match the original data frame which makes the division fail. On the other hand, `transform` keeps the shape of the data frame, but produces aggregated values.